# WPF - Telerik issue? Working fine in Windows 7 environment but not Windows 8.1

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

[image]

Hi, guys. I know the information is sort of brief but can any good souls here, able to point out to me what does this error message means exactly?

The codes are running just fine at Windows 7 platform. However, it crashes when I use Windows 8.1 to run it.

I am almost sure that the problem has something to do with ***telerik***. This is because when I remove the related ***RadGridView*** from my ***xaml***, it works fine. That ***RadGridView*** is **binding** an **ICollection** as its **ItemSource**.

Quite desperate at the moment. Thank you in advance for any help guys! Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by touch screen / accessibility support in Windows 8.x

You might be able to solve this by disabling UI automation in Telerik like this:

```
using Telerik.Windows.Automation.Peers; 

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AutomationManager.AutomationMode = AutomationMode.Disabled;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100 If this does not work try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36252796/5152001) also

Comment: will try it out and come bak to you :D

Comment: Hi @Gled, it seems that I can't use AutomationManager. It is underlined with red, stating that it does not exist in the current context. I have included the "using Telerik.Windows.Automation.Peers" line